# The driver executable does not exist: D:\Firefox\geckodriver.exe

Tags: java, selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class sasas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(appUrl);
        System.out.println("Test script executed successfully.");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

this is the sample code i am trying. when i run i get the error message as **"The driver executable does not exist: D:\Firefox\geckodriver.exe"** please help me to proceed. i added the location in environmental variable then too i get this error . PATH i added as D:\Samplecode.

kindly help me

Comment: Where do you keep `geckodriver.exe` file?

Answer (score 1):

(1) To use gecko driver, make sure you are using Firefox version 55 and above to get better gecko Web-Driver feature support, find out more [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/)

(2) Perhaps, you should downgrade Selenium to a lower version i.e. version 2.53.1. Selenium version 2.53.1 runs perfectly on Firefox 47.0.1 and lower, does not require using web driver API. I have ran your code against this and it worked fine.

public class Sasas {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(appUrl);
    System.out.println("Test script executed successfully.");
    driver.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use the relative path:

JAVA

1.- In your project, create the **Drivers/Win/Firefox/geckodriver.exe** folder and add your .exe

2.- Replace:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");
```

For:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Drivers/Win/Firefox/Geckodriver.exe";

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path);
```

***Note: using the relative path is the most optimal***